# Iterated LinearOptimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

One common method for solving large linear optimization problems is "column generation". That method is in essence the "revised simplex" method with one change: given a current dual solution, rather than simply search through a given list of primal variables to find one whose dual constraint is violated, column generation solves an optimization problem to generate a primal variable whose dual constraint is (most) violated.

Once it finds a new variable, column generation adds that to the "master problem" and continues.

My question is this: A brute force implementation of column generation would append the new variable to the problem (or the new constraint to the dual problem) and re-solve. But that forces LinearOptimization to repeat all the steps in finding an optimal solution to the problem without the new variable (or dual constraint). Is there a way to mimic the "revised simplex" in Mathematica and simply add the new variable to the list of columns and continue on with the optimization?

Comment: Can you add some code and an example?